# Does airflow support the cloud-sql-python-connector for connecting to CloudSQL Postgres?

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-sql

Airflow uses SQLAlchemy to connect to the DB: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-up-database.html#database-uri

Google has official support for connecting to CloudSQL via the `cloud-sql-python-connector` package: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-connectors#examples

It looks like it even supports the IAM integration for Postgres which makes things even more seamless: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector/commit/6703232d6ea624f868e750c8c49c3bb1151f1f1e#diff-f5a708e43b65d84f59aa4fd685978087acc7e903b740f3e45c68356dbb2fd7b4R77

This is so you don't have to use the CloudSQL proxy (or use private networking/firewalling) and can connect directly in python like this:

```
# The Cloud SQL Python Connector can be used along with SQLAlchemy using the
# 'creator' argument to 'create_engine'
def init_connection_engine() -> sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:
    def getconn() -> pg8000.dbapi.Connection:
        conn: pg8000.dbapi.Connection = connector.connect(
            os.environ["POSTGRES_CONNECTION_NAME"],
            "pg8000",
            user=os.environ["POSTGRES_USER"],
            password=os.environ["POSTGRES_PASS"],
            db=os.environ["POSTGRES_DB"],
        )
        return conn

    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        "postgresql+pg8000://",
        creator=getconn,
    )
    engine.dialect.description_encoding = None
    return engine
```

Can I install `cloud-sql-python-connector` in airflow and just set the connection to use it in my [sql_alchemy_conn](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/set-config.html) settings?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, yes, you can install `cloud-sql-python-connector` in airflow. Tried it on my end as well.

[image]

Below is the sample configuration on how to setup `sql_alchemy_conn`.

```js
def init_connection_engine() -> sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:
        def getconn() -> pg8000.dbapi.Connection:
            conn: pg8000.dbapi.Connection = connector.connect(
                CONNECTION_NAME,
                "pg8000",
                user=MYSQL_USER,
                password=MYSQL_PASS,
                db=DB_NAME,
            )
            return conn

        engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
            "postgresql+pg8000://",
            creator=getconn,
        )
        engine.dialect.description_encoding = None

        query = sqlalchemy.text("SELECT * FROM entries")

        with engine.connect() as db_conn:
            results = db_conn.execute(query)
            for result in results:
                logging.info(result)
       
       process_data = python.PythonOperator(
        task_id='query_postgre',
        python_callable=init_connection_engine,
        provide_context=True
        )
```

Comment: Im confused where do you put the above snippet? I thought you could only configure the connection with the settings file and it had to just be a string. Also, how did you install the package in the airflow environment? Im not going to make the connection manually in DAG code I'm using the settings to configure the connection for all DAGs.

Comment: Snippet is placed inside a PythonOperator. You may also refer in this GCP [doc](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-package). Lastly, getConn() does not accept 1 liner environment variable. Updated my code snippet. @red888

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm looking for. I want to setup a postgres database backend with the cloud-sql-python-connector and the IAM integration. Also, you linked to composer docs which I am not using.